# Check device is locked?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've a multitasking application and I'm using all the app delegate events for backgrounding but when the device locked or idle timer expires none of the delegate events get fired. So I need to check device lock status.

Is there way to do this with SDK(non private api solution)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can watch after an item in the Keychain :

kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked
The data in the keychain item can be accessed only while the device is unlocked by the user. This is recommended for items that need to be accesible only while the application is in the foreground. Items with this attribute migrate to a new device when using encrypted backups.
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared in SecItem.h.

From : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion it sounds like you could use [`applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable:)

> On a device that uses content protection, protected files are stored in an encrypted form and made available only while the device is unlocked. This notification lets your application know that the device is about to be locked and that any protected files it is currently accessing will be unavailable shortly.
>
> If your application is currently accessing a protected file, you can use this method to release any references to that file. Although it is not an error to access the file while the device is locked, any attempts to do so will fail. Therefore, if your application depends on the file, you might want to take steps to avoid using that file while the device is locked.

I assume this will get called regardless of whether or not you are using protected files. I have not tested it yet though.